# Account not deleting from the database. I am getting no feedback JSP and Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, servlets

I'm trying to delete the user from the Account relation. However, it doesn't seem to work. The code runs all the way with no problem as the console does not display any error. I am not sure why this isn't working. In DeleteMemberController, I used doGet() because doDelete() simply wasn't working so I made a separate Controller.

MemberDao.java

```
public static void deleteMember(int id){
/**
 * This method will delete the member from the database.
 */
  try {
    connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("delete from Account where user_id = ?");
    ps.setInt(1,id);
    ps.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

DeleteMemberController.java

```
public class DeleteMemberController extends HttpServlet {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   MemberDao memDao;
   private static String HOME = "/";

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,IOException {
       HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
       Integer id = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user_id");
       memDao.deleteMember(id); 
       req.getRequestDispatcher(HOME).forward(req, resp);
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure your doGet is getting processed, perhaps you are **post**ing it, and u have a n empty `doPost` ?  
2. What database are you using?  
3. Instead of delete, can you use select and check if u have any matching records for that user_id?

Comment: @codevalid I am using ms access as the database. The user has to be logged in to delete their account. I don't know if it would make sense to select and check if the user exists. Also in the jsp file I have the method = "GET".

Comment: Have you double checked that your `id` parameter actually holds the correct id?